# Camera Pose Calibration

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, camera-pose-calibration, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an equivalent package to **camera pose calibration** in ROS Hydro? Finding the exact transform connecting the frame of a new camera to an existing robot's **tf** tree is almost impossible ...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192305/camera-pose-calibration/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2014-09-09

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Similar packages are [industrial_extrinsic_cal](http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_extrinsic_cal) for ROS Hydro, and [camera_pose_calibration](https://github.com/delftrobotics/camera_pose_calibration) for ROS Indigo.

---

Originally posted by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) with karma: 529 on 2017-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-06-13**:
These aren't maintained anymore, and they're not even well documented.